# Is fastq really that important?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues

[Lea Tano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987441/lea-tano) is currently adding the [fastq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastq) tag to many questions. I saw that many times in suggested edits, e.g. [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105342/replace-any-line-that-starts-with-the-symbol-using-sed-awk-cut), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7416281) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7416368) and maybe you find others.

The comment is copy/paste:

> Comment: add new tag - fastq tag is important to the question

I'm not sure whether [fastq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastq) is really that important. It seems to me that [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) are sufficient to answer the question and it is more or less accidentally related to [fastq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastq).

For now I skipped about 5 of those reviews. Should I reject them?

---

There were two more ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7416721) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7416655)) until I reached the review limit of 20.

From the comments I think it was good that I personally skipped them and leave this task open to others.

Comment: My opinion is that it seems to apply just fine to the first example.  Knowing about the file format could be very important and might help with other questions about working with that file format.  The second example seems dubious to me.  That question is really about GZip files.

Comment: Its completely off for the 3rd-  they're asking about how to download data.  The type of file format is irrelevant.  I also think the bioinformatics tag is incorrect there, but that wasn't an edit.  I don't think it makes sense on the 2nd either.  The first is fine.

Comment: Left a comment for the editor to look here. BTW: He seems to have just created that tag.

Comment: The user has mass tagged [95 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987441/lea-tano?tab=allactions&sort=revisions) in the span of a day. Whether or not the tag is relevant, they should space it out and spend more time thinking about whether or not the tag actually fits the question.

Comment: I [approved the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7407532) that marked the introduction of this tag. It seemed (and indeed seems) to fit that question. Subsequent mass tagging doesn't seem to have been quite so careful. [inb4 "so *you're* the weak link!" comments?]

Comment: My first honest impression was "wtf is fastq? FAST Question?" Then I see that the format of the files to manipulate are "Fastq". I see the point when we add xml tag to any question about the xml format (something that I just don't understand either). I would say, you want to manipulate a text only file, just tag it with the tools you are using for such task. Period.

Comment: The Bioinformatics equivalent of Stack Overflow, Biostars, has [289 questions tagged fastq](https://www.biostars.org/t/fastq/).

Comment: I handled about 15 of the `fastq` edits yesterday, and rejected about half, where the fact that the file was fastq was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I notice that user was awarded the taxonomist badge yesterday.  How many of those reviews would you all have had to do if the taxonomist badge didn't exist?

Comment: In my opinion `fastq` tags should be replaced by the `bioinformatics` tag. I guess everyone working in this field is familiar with the file format. It does not add much to have a tag for every single file format used in bioinformatics.

Comment: Does seem like the sole purpose was to achieve the Taxonomist badge, rather than improving the posts.

Comment: Maybe the Mortarboard badge was another reason for the mass tagging.

Comment: I reviewed several of the edits and rolled a few back where the `fastq` tag was entirely irrelevant: questions about shell scripts, directories, zip files, etc. The fact that I left a few doesn't mean I like the tag: I don't. Few if any other file formats have tags: I don't see why this should be an exception.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It’s true that [FASTQ](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/385/29) is a core file format in bioinformatics. It’s extremely important.

However, with the exception of one little detail (quality encoding, for those interested), it’s also trivial in the context of programming. It’s just a text file with very little that sets its format apart, and it’s of limited technical interest. It’s like tagging lots of questions with [txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/txt). For most of the questions, **especially** those tagged by user Lea Tano, it seems completely irrelevant that the format in question is FASTQ. It adds no information, and I’d go as far as saying that all those suggested edits from Lea are spam.

Comment: I agree that the `fastq` tag is not very helpful. As a side note: We have a `bioinformatics` tag for that. There are a couple of `core file formats` in bioinformatics, depending on the field. If we introduce a `fastq` tag, then one can argue that we need tags for `dssp` and `pdb`, and different aligment formats as well.

Comment: @cel: `.pdb` is an extension used by Windows VC++ to mark files storing debug information for libraries; `pdb` could introduce some ambiguity.

Comment: What are the criteria for creating a new tag? They're only useful for searching or following. If you can simply search the term already, and nobody's going to be following the tag, then it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I look at it like this:

There's over 20,000 questions tagged with [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv). It's just delimited text like this is. This file format doesn't seem conceptually different from csv except that more people use csv. If I was using sed/awk to parse a csv, I would expect [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csv) to be allowed. I don't see what the difference is, or what the problem is.

This answer is not about whether or not each of Lea's individual edits were valid - just whether or not the idea of tagging questions with [fastq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fastq) is appropriate in general.

Comment: *Many* more people. *Many orders of magnitude* more people. I had never even heard of `fastq` until I read this page, and I've been doing IT since 1971. The implication of allowing `fastq` as a tag is that we have a tag per file format, in which case I have about 65 new tags to introduce.

Comment: Are we worried we'll run out of tags?

Comment: @corsiKa, not so much about running out of tags, but about creating ambiguous tags. See for example the `pdb` file format and `pdb`, the python debugger.